# How to filter fields in documents with security rules

Tags: firebase-security, projection, google-cloud-firestore

I am experimenting with Cloud Firestore security rules. Is it possible to filter document fields?

For example if you have a document

```
{
  name: "John Doe",
  email: "doe@example.com"
}
```

then some users aren't allowed to get the document with the email address. Their application requests the document with

```
firebase.firestore.doc('users/doe-uid')
```

and gets this document

```
{
  name: "John Doe",
}
```

If yes, how?

I think it should be possible because the [Cloud Firestore Security Rules Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security) says in the first sentence (emphasis is mine):

> Cloud Firestore Security Rules are used to determine who has read and write access to collections and documents stored in Cloud Firestore, as well as how documents are structured and **what fields and values they contain**.

However I couldn't find anything in the reference telling me how to filter out fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firestore rules are not filters, they're a server-side validation of document queries, meaning that you access (or not) the whole document, not particular fields.

The piece of documentation you mentionned means that you can do data validation on fields.
Here is a basic example of rules validating data on a write query (via `request.resource.data`) :

```
match /users/{userId} {
    allow write: if request.resource.data.age is int;
}
```

Here is another basic example that uses an existing field to validate a read query (via `resource.data`) :

```
match /articles/{articleId} {
    allow read: if resource.data.isPublished == true;
}
```

To filter out fields, you have do it client side, after the query.

Now If you want to secure access to certain fields, you have to create another collection (look into [subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data)) with a different set of rules, and make another query that will match these rules.

Comment: I accepted this and separated the public and private data in two documents and today I deployed a working test. I still think that the documentation is misleading. But that's life. Suck it up and go on.